# And function, one cell equal to an entire column

Tags: excel

Currently using this formula: =IF(AND(M$5=C5,$L6=A5),B:B,"ERROR")

Works great when i specifically reference the cells to match, C5 and A5. However, I'd like to make this the entire range of column C and A but I keep getting "ERROR" returned. Is this possible?

Comment: close with ctrl+shift+enter to make it an array formula. that might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To slightly revise the answer suggested in the comment by @user2697139, you will want to do this with an Array Formula. An array formula works by performing the same operation multiple times, over a range of cells. It then gives you an array of results, one for each cell. To get a single answer, you need to collapse using another function (like SUM, MIN, AND, etc). Usually AND is a poor way to do this but in your case it is what you want.

To perform this test, simply do the following:

```
=AND(M5=C:C,L6=A:A)
```

This will show you TRUE if M5 matches all values in column C, and L6 matches all values in column A. Otherwise it will show FALSE. Note that too many formulas like this will take a long time to process as an Array Formula which references an entire column performs the operation 1M times.

I Can't tell how you want B:B to factor into this, however. Could you elaborate on that if it matters? Explain how your data is actually laid out and what you want the results to be.

Comment: So I have data pulled from a Live Office query in columns A, B and C.  I am trying to match the data in column A to a set of cells L15 through L40.  I am then trying to match the data in column C to cells M14 through Y14. If both match, I'd like to pull the data in column B into the corresponding table cell, M15:Y40. Essentially, it seems I'm trying to build a pivot table. however, due to live office a traditional table would not work as well and require constant refreshing. True, False etc (typical returns from AND functions) is not the ultimate output. The data in B:B is returned if true.